# How to increase keyboard height like SwiftKey?

Tags: ios, ios8-extension, ios-keyboard-extension

The height of a typical keyboard extension in iOS 8 is like the [ELDeveloperKeyboard](https://github.com/Kamaros/ELDeveloperKeyboard) at right . How to increase the height of the keyboard similar to Swiftkey at left?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple documentation about [Custom Keyboards](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html):

[image]